# How to get index of element in array that in second place?

Tags: swift

I have an array [a,b,a,c,d]

I can get index of first `a` by `array.index(where:{$0 is a})`

How can I get index of second item `a` ?

Comment: You have to write that function yourself. But it's not that hard. You can do it!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples:

```
let xs = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "d"]
let ys = xs.indices.filter { xs[$0] == "a" }
print(ys) // [0, 2]

// or

let zs = xs.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element == "a" ? $0.offset : nil }
print(zs) // [0, 2]
```